# Display video thumbnail from web url

Tags: android, video, thumbnails

I have to display video thumbnail in a listview from web url.

Currently I'm using library FFMpegMediaRetreiver:

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
            mmr.setDataSource(url);
            mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
            mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);

            time = convertTime(mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));

            Bitmap b = mmr.getFrameAtTime(2000000, FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST); // frame at 2 seconds
            mmr.release();
```

But size of libraries is about 23 mb. Is there another way to display thumbnail without sacrificing memory?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the size of apk generated?

Comment: 56.1 mb with library and 39.5 without.

Comment: That's because the library contains .so files for all 4 supported Android architectures. In order to reduce the size of your application I recommend generating an APK for each individual architecture.